# python yfinance to give return on investment for an etf that reinvests dividends (accumulates)

Tags: python, yfinance

first poster :)

My question concerns using yfinance when looking at an ETF that accumulates rather than pays a dividend.

I am attempting to use yfinance library to determine the return on an investment between the buy and sell point of a share (etf ticker SWDA.L on the London Stock Exchange in this case).

My sample code is below but I do not think yfinance accounts for any value that will have been gained from reinvested dividends from the fund, it only considers buy and sell price at unit price.

I am aware of the dictionaries available on some shares include 'ytdReturn' but this isn't available for SWDA.L. And I am attempting to gain return between two defined dates.

Any help hugely appreciated, from extensive searching I cannot find articles close. I wonder if the package considers this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import easygui as easygui
import yfinance as yf
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import simpledialog

swda= yf.Ticker("swda.l")
data = yf.download("swda.l")

buy_date = '2022-08-01'
sell_date = '2023-08-01'

print(swda.info)

buy_price = data.loc[buy_date,'Adj Close']
sell_price = data.loc[sell_date,'Adj Close']

perc_gain = (((sell_price-buy_price)/buy_price))
price_gain = (perc_gain)*buy_price

print(('Percent gain is:'+str(perc_gain)))
print('Buy price was:'+str(buy_price))
print('Sell price was:'+str(sell_price))
print('Price gain is:'+str(price_gain))
```